# Как можно пробежатьcя по кнопкам?

Tags: c#, winforms

В Windows Forms например, если создать 9 кнопок, можно ли по ним пробежаться и изменить в них текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls) // получаем все контролы на данной форме
{
   if(c is Button)
   {         
       Button button = с as Button;
       // это кнопка, делайте что надо
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: А зачем вы откатили редактирование? Вы не в курсе, как сопоставление шаблона с присваиванием работает? Это была не ошибка. По вашей версии даже сама студия предложит это исправить на то что я написал автоматически.

Comment: Вот, почитайте https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression

Comment: Я в курсе, но мне кажется, что первоначальный вариант более понятный